# Getting to the subclass from superclass objects list

Tags: java

I have one class, let's say - `Animal`. And a couple of classes that inherit from it, let's say: `Bird`, `Cat`, `Dog`.

Now I create an array list of type Animal, and add some instances of the subclasses to it.

```
private List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(new Bird());
list.add(new Bird());
list.add(new Cat());
list.add(new Dog());
```

Then I iterate through this list, call some methods, etc.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   list.get(i).makeSound();
}
```

Fine. But what if I want to add to the `Bird` subclass a method, that won't be implemented in the `Animal` superclass? Let's say, `fly()` method, so it would look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   list.get(i).makeSound();
   if(list.get(i) instanceof Bird)
   {
      list.get(i).fly(); // error here
   }
}
```

It makes sense, but it throws an error - can't find the symbol. Implementing the method in the `Animal` class seems to solve the issue, but it hurts my eyes when I have to do that a couple of times. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: What is this - `ArrayList<Animal> list = new List<Animal>;`? I count two compile time errors on that line alone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to `Bird`:

```
((Bird)list.get(i)).fly();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already determined that it's a `Bird`, then you can cast your `Animal` as a `Bird`, which allows you to call `fly()`.

```
if(list.get(i) instanceof Bird)
{
   Bird bird = (Bird) list.get(i);
   bird.fly();
}
```

Comment: Probably best to mention that getting `i` from the list twice isn't such a good idea. And in any case the OP should be using an enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'Cast' back to an instance of bird.

```
if(list.get(i) instanceof Bird)
{
    Bird bird = ((Bird) list.get(i));
}
```

I would also rewrite your loop to be a 'for each' loop as well:

```
for(Animal animal : list)
{
   animal.makeSound();
   if(animal instanceof Bird)
   {
      ((Bird) animal).fly(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its an array of animal references , only you know what the reference is actually pointing to , need to let the compiler know that via casting...  at compile time the compiler will check the animal . class file and see if there is a makeNoise metbod , if there is it will not throw an error, at run time it will follow the animal reference amd see what it is actually pointing to and call that classes makeNoise metbod , as u stated there is no makeNoise method in your animal class so , yes casting is necessary. ...